# Cross messaging webview & multiple windows

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app, postmessage

I'm working on a packaged app, as follows:

- Window 1:: Has a webview, where a postMessage method is used to communicate between the webview and window.

Is it possible to send messages from the Webview in (Window 1) to a different window (i.e. Window 2) other than the parent window it is in?!
or another way, can the background script listen to the postMessage?

I tried playing with the appWindow.source from the page within the Webview but couldn't manage it.
is it possible? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can send message from webview to window and then that window is able to send message to window2.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/messaging

Comment: I'm aware of that method, but I want Data sent from Window1 to webview (in the same window) to be recieved by Window2 directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-sendMessage) and [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onMessage) to broadcast the messages received from the webview to other windows.

So the window that has the webview would act as a proxy to send/receive messages to other windows. It would have some code like this:

```
 window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const message = event.data;
    console.log(`viewer window is broadcasting message from webview: ${JSON.stringify(event.data)}`);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(event.data);
});

const webview = document.querySelector('webview');
webview.addEventListener('loadstop', () => {
    webview.contentWindow.postMessage({from: 'app', cmd: 'init'}, webview.src);
});

function handleMessage(message) {
    if (message.from === 'anotherwindow') {
        console.log('webview window received message from another window, sending it to webview');
        webview.contentWindow.postMessage(message, webview.src);
    }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
```